# Is using Bootstrap with Material design a bad practice?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-material

In my Anguar2 project I am using [angular-material](https://material.angular.io/). As I want this responsive, I thought of using Bootstrap grid system. I have heard about flex-layout and it seems most of the users recomend it. 
I thought of using bootstrap as I have prior experience in it.
Is this a bad practice?

Comment: Are you only wanting to use bootstrap to leverage it's grid system?

Comment: You can use them together, it's not bad practice.

Comment: @cwanjt yes. That's why I am having this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing called a bad practice or good practice when it comes to choosing a framework. It all depends on your requirements and comfort zones. However I would like to highlight some benefits of flex-layout here:

- Easy to learn
- Good support
- Small in size compared to bootstrap module
- With time as
  the flex-layout evolves it will be fully baked Better support for
  multiple device sizes.
- Things like AOT and Build-Optimizer helps to make it minuscule as compared to bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

I personally believe that it's better to use frameworks which I am comfortable with if deadlines are near. Bootstrap is undoubtedly good especially because of it's huge community base.
However, if you have time then I suggest that you try these:

[Materialize CSS](http://materializecss.com)

[Angular Material](https://material.angular.io)

Materialize CSS has a really efficient grid system.

Comment: I am already using Angular Material. Grid system in there, is not much easy to use as Bootstrap. Is there something I missed?

Comment: @LasithaYapa every framework has it's own style. I've used angular material and yes, it is not like bootstrap but I suggest that you improve on it's practices.